# Core data: 64 bit: Transformable value not upgraded

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a table with several transformable values. Some of them has a defined transformer name, and some don't (see attached picture).

[image: A field with and empty Value Transformer Name]

I am now making my code 64 bit compatible and have encountered the following problem:

1. Install previous up (was built only for 32 bit target)
2. Upgrade to new version (64 bit)
3. Fetching from core data an entity with a predicate of a value that has some defined Value Transformer Name. Success.
4. Fetching from core data an entity with a predicate of a value that DOESN'T have a defined Value Transformer Name. Fail, I get zero results.

I opened the database with some SQLiteBrowser and its content seems to be intact. This only happens on 64bit devices (32 bit behaves normally).

Any ideas why this is happening and how to solve this?

Thanks,

Nili